# How do bookmakers set their odds?

Tags: probability-theory, gambling

I am and always was fascinated by **how oddmakers set their odds**.

With almost everyone I have previously discussed this question, they always say something along the lines of:

> 'Duh, they set the odds in a way that they 'split' the bettors in half
>   (the total potential payout) and they, the betmakers, get their profit
>   by setting their odds (slightly) smaller than their final payout will
>   be.'

And this sounds, to me, not *that* logical (on the other hand it does sound pretty smart).

If we take the (presumably fair) coin-toss as an example, the most logical (to me) offered bets would be something like 1.98€ for each outcome (only tail or head is possible), for each 1€ bet.

But, according to the logic above, oddmakers would set the odds at any point which splits the pot, and that could be anywhere (if for any reason the bettors would almost entirely prefer one side of the coin).

I get that the oddmakers probably would set their odds not completely even and move them in the direction of the 'split-pot' to decrease their risk (by not having to pay out more than they previously amassed in the event of the unfavorable outcome).

I hope this illustrates my disconnection to the answer above.

So how does this work in reality, where it seems to be way more difficult to built a model to realistically evaluate the chances of specific games (e.g. soccer matches, who seem to be very close/coincidental/luck-dependant)?

1. Do bookmakers just resort to the 'split the pot'-approach?
2. Are there some (betting) reinsurers?
3. Is there scientific literature (regarding the approach of oddmaking)?
4. How does this affect potential arbitrage opportunities (in my opinion the above 'answer' leads almost surely to some sort of arbitrage opportunity at specific points in time; but my minimal experience has shown me there is, obviously, none)?

I appreciate any answer and would welcome any discussion (in a sense, if there is a place where something like this can be rather discussed than answered I would love if someone can point me that direction), thanks in advance.

---

Note: bet makers, oddmakers, betting providers, bookmakers all means the same to me.

Comment: There isn't a short answer to this.  It's a combination of things. [Pari Mutuel betting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parimutuel_betting) involves no choices from the bookie.  In situations that do:   Market factors of course...who is willing to bet how much on this or that outcome.  And, of course, professional handicappers set expectations.  In practice, the usual best (short) answer is "the bookie takes whatever bet they  believe they can offset profitably at that point in time."

Comment: To your specific questions:  successful bookies try to avoid taking actual risk on a game.  So if, for whatever reason, the crowd all thought the fair coin was going to come up Heads, the bookie would give the Tails side better odds in order to get them to bet.   What else are they to do?  If $90\%$ of the pot was on Heads and Heads came up, they'd go broke.

Comment: **What else are they to do?** If there was another bookmaker B, I, as the bookmaker A with the 90% heads bettors, would try to 'reinsure' me by maximizing my potential payout given that I know the 'real' chance of head is 50% by betting heads at B.

Comment: Well, obviously if they can offset the bet without going to the market then they can remove their risk that way.  But...of course...that just begs the question.  How does the other bookie set the bet?

Comment: I think you are being mislead by the fact that you are imagining a situation in which you believe there are true, mathematically unique, probabilities.  The real world very seldom offers such situations.  There aren't "super bookmakers" who establish the odds on sporting events mathematically, though of course there are gamblers who will try to step in if they see that the market bets are implying improbable odds.

Comment: I know, the other bookie sets it according to his own risk/profit-preference. The thing I don't seem to grasp, why would the bookie, assuming he truly knows the actual odds, set them vastly different than the odds the bettors indicate by their betting other than maximizing his payout (according to some risk/profit tradeoff).

Comment: **There aren't "super bookmakers" who establish the odds on sporting events mathematically...** That is the thing I don't understand, why wouldn't they? E.g. another game where the bettors don't know the outcome, but the bookie knows. According to the previous logic the bookie would set them somewhere close to the assumed odds although, to truly profit, shoudln't he set the odds more tilted favoring the the outcome which won't happen?

Comment: But of course the bookies payout (unless he is an idiot) should not be solely a function of how the event turns out.  He should make money on the spread...that is the difference between the money taken in and the money paid out.

Comment: The usual way a bookie fails is by choosing not to cover some deep out of the money bet.  Sure, it;'s tempting to just keep the money...why pay to hedge a (virtually) non-existent risk?  And that's fine if the exposure is low, but if it isn't?  There's always the chance somebody knows something you don't.  Or maybe they are just luckier than you.

Comment: To the question in the last comment:  In the end, the Market sets the odds.  The bookie can only set the spread (and even that is competitive).  Of course, a good bookie has professional insight into things and if they see the odds going sideways they should have a long list of names they can call to induce them to take advantage.  But, honestly, betting against the wisdom of crowds is a rough game.  Crowds are a lot smarter than you think.

Comment: There is, of course, no shortage of gamblers who do what you suggest.  Set odds based on careful analysis and place bets accordingly.  Very common activity.  But those people are not bookmakers.  The latter work in volume.  Huge volume.  Volume far exceeding their personal risk appetite.  If they can make a riskless $1\%$ or whatever off that huge volume, that's a business.

Comment: ** Crowds are a lot smarter than you think** I'm aware of that and I am personally way to risk-averse to gamble, but I am just interested in this topic. Thanks a lot for your answers, they are very insightful and logical. I am going to elaborate more tommorow. My big grievance with this topic is that I am just missing my intuition regarding why betting (in some capacity) not according to the 'true' odds isn't  (always) the best strategy .

Comment: The main thing to keep in mind:  Bookies are not betting.  Period.  They are not taking risk, or they shouldn't be.  They want volume.  They just want more people to bet, so long as they can always offset the bet.

Comment: @lulu Can bookies change the (fixed) odds over time?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No.   In Pari Mutuel pools the odds are only set at the end (but bookies aren't involved).  But if you place a bet with a bookie the odds are negotiated and set at that moment.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Pari Mutuel systems, like bets at the horse track, are simple.  You pay $\$1$, or whatever, and buy a ticket for whichever side you want.  All that money is thrown into a pot.  At the end the pot is distributed evenly to the winning tickets (after some percentage has been extracted by the House).  The odds are not determined until the last bet has been placed.  That's why the odds at the race track are so volatile.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. I wasn't thinking of *pari mutuel*. What I meant was the following. If today I go to the bookie and place a bet, the odds for that bet are fixed. Can you go to the same bookie tomorrow and place a bet on the same outcome at fixed odds different from mine? I assume the fixed odds do change over time, though the odds are fixed for every bet actually made. Hence, the bookie can use voodoo analytics to set initial fixed odds, and then market forces (and arbitrageurs looking for free money) dictate the evolution of fixed odds at each bookie.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Oh, of course.  The bet I place on Monday might be unavailable on Tuesday.  Absolutely.  New information comes out, the market shifts.  And sure, the early bets are likely to be set according to what the handicappers think but after that the market takes over.

Comment: @lulu Exactly. The OP's focus seems to be on what I would consider the least interesting part — the initial fixed odds. I find it much more interesting how the bookies consume new information and adjust the fixed odds, what algorithms they do use. This is closer to *dynamic pricing* (Uber comes to mind) than probability theory per se. Closer to economics, mechanism design, market design. How to create the incentives for bettors to take the risk off the bookies' books. Fascinating stuff.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Agreed, it's fascinating.  Challenging job, the bookmaker (or the Market Maker on an Exchange for all that).  A big bet comes in...you have to decide how you'll be able to lay it off, and how quickly.  Easy to get wrong.

Comment: RodrigodeAzevedo and @lulu Thank you both for the discussion, it surely is an interesting topic (especially the market making process). I guess my main takeaway is **bookies are not betting**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a simple explanation:

The odds are usually not presented as percentages, but as "decimal" odds, which can be obtained dividing the percentage by 1: 50% / 1 = 2. In the case of X 62%, -X 48%, the decimal odds are: X 1.61, -X 2.08.

The decimal odds indicate what you would get as reward in case you win. Notice therefore that outcomes with higher estimations of happening pay a lower reward, and outcomes with lower estimations of happening pay a higher reward.

1. They make an initial informed estimate of probabilities of a given outcome given their expert knowledge of the sport, they definitely have some expert analysts as well as some statistical models -based on previous results-. In this case, let's say, they predict X has a chance for them of 50%, so the odds so far are: X 50%, -X 50%. It is secret what method each bookmaker uses exactly, so you will never know unless you become the bookmaker yourself, or work with them as the expert; however many possible methods, beyond the intuitive informed opinion, are well known: looking at league standing, categorizing the teams by recent performance, seeing previous encounters of the same teams, using the statistics of the goals scored in previous games to make a poisson distribution, calculating an ELO rating for each team or even each player, etc.
2. They add a premium (also known as "vig"), to their prediction, which they might win. This is actually their earning in the long term. Notice that in the previous step, both possibilities, X winning and X losing added to 100%, they just add to that total some percentage points, let's say 10 points, so they will add to 110%. That 10% is their long term earning because, they are actually paying, in the long term, getting 10% more than they would to get even odds (long term). The way they distribute this premium (vig) among the outcomes is unknown and probably different for each particular bookmaker, some may add it equally (which would be the intuitive way) so it would be: X 55%, -X 55%; some may add more to some option, like X 52%, -X 58%; and some may want to compensate for the favorite, PERHAPS (a very speculative perhaps) even giving better odds than they even estimated originally to one that is not a favorite, like X 62%, -X 48%.
3. As the days pass and the game is about to start, the odds get adjusted according to new information and according to the market demand, to compensate each side in case one is getting many bets and another is not.

The art of betting systematically, is therefore about trying to find odds that are better than the "reality" offered by the bookmaker. For example, if the bookmaker is offering these odds: X 55%, -X 55%, which seem to indicate that both outcomes have same chance, your way to beat them would be to find out that some outcome has different chances than these estimations, for example, if we know that actually X has a chance of 60% of winning, we should bet for X indeed, as the actual reward (if it were even with the probabilities) in decimal odds should be 1.67 (corresponding to 60% chances of happening), but it is actually paying 1.82 (corresponding to 55% implied chances).

This means, we will bet ¤1, and if the odds were exactly as the probabilities, it should pay back the same ¤1 we bet plus ¤.67; and this way in the long term, if we played infinitely in average we would end with ¤1 anyway, because the reward is even with the chances. However, given that the odds are in our favor, we will bet ¤1 and we will get ¤1 plus ¤.82, which is ¤.15 higher than what would be even, that, in the long term, is our earning.

Even if we lose this bet, if we only bet to favorable odds like these, we will have an earning in the long term.

Now, this sounds easy but there are 2 details:

1. It is VERY HARD to find actual mistakes on their estimations or, as they call them, market inefficiencies: it is very hard to calculate the chances of an event, and very hard to calculate exactly how much is their "mistake". Even if we know they are wrong, without knowing how wrong they are, it is hard to calculate how much to bet.
2. If we somehow manage to find out how much is our advantage, we still have to know how much to bet on each bet, which is actually not as intuitive as it sounds. Luckily there exists an already mathematically proven formula to know what percentage of your bankroll you have to gamble on each bet, depending on the advantage you have, which should, in the long term, give you the highest possible profit. This is called the "Kelly criterion". However, this only works if you know well what is your advantage, and if you don't, this bankroll management will lead you to loses and bankruptcy very fast, because this is a precise calculation based on your advantage: if that number is wrong you will lose a lot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).